# Is love from families a necessity for children to form normal relationship?

Tags: social-psychology, developmental-psychology

Some human skills need specific input during childhood to develop, such as language skills. Is the ability to love one of them? I.e., does the formulation of intimate relationship with partner (or any other relationship, like with kids or friends) require the input of love from family members during childhood?

Related research can be, like, can victims of domestic violence form normal and long-lasting relationships when they grow up? Or any dataset/survey/study on similar focus?

Comment: Hi Ryan, welcome at CogSci and interesting question. It is however a bit too broad. The different troubles you refer to can have many different effects on many different people. Perhaps it is an idea to focus on just one the bullet points instead, such as the ffects of domestic violence on forming relationships. Then you can always post some additional questions with a focus on one of the other points.

Comment: @RobinKramer Thanks Robin. I made substantial modification to my question and plz let me know if it is appropriate.

Comment: A lot better. I am no specialist in this topic, unfortunately, but I am looking forward for someone who can shine a light on this topic.

Comment: If you look at [Bowlby's Attachment Theory](https://www.simplypsychology.org/bowlby.html) (see also: [this question](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/19312/7604)) love from families is very important, and I would say it is necessary for early emotional development. But; love, respect and support from others later in life (if enough is provided) can repair damage caused by familial disrespect.

Answer (score 0):

not being an expert in developmental psychology i cant give precise information but i have recently been listen several of "the great courses" on human development and personality.

i think the consensus of modern (and a large extent of more "vintage" research) would support the idea that we need affection and the security that having a relationship with caregiver provides. (bowlbys monkeys etc). any diusruption to this kind of input will have an affect on development. i did read an interesting study (i think it was an Italian university) on the development of psychopathic traits in abused children, so i think its probably safe to say that the trend certainly lies in the direction that says forming relationships needs some reciprocal affection.

i wouldnt go as far as to say that authoritarian parents  = less love-capable offspring, people are to complex for such a basic interpretation. there is also the issue of CBT and other treatments in helping to develop these bonds. i think most parents would probably agree that they didnt really know as much about love as they thought until they had children to care for.

Comment: Adding the sources would really help.